# Date time in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, date, time

My df has a column of datetime having values like "16 jul 1940-12:45"
I want to change it to dd/mm/yy
Format..how I can do it.

I tried to solve it by the following code but failed and gave me the error.
Df[col]=df[col].dt.strftime(%d-%m-%y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%d %b %Y-%H:%M')
#old -- > 16 jul 1940-12:45
#new -- > 1940-07-16 12:45:00

#or

df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%d %b %Y-%H:%M').dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
#old -- > 16 jul 1940-12:45
#new -- > 16/07/1940
```